# wordpress allow only to add comments

Tags: wordpress

How do I restrict users **only to add comments**?

That is, **disallow edit or delete of a comment**.

I need to do it programmatically from a plugin. It should only affect the currently rendered post.

Comment: Any interesting hook I'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Role Scoper](https://wordpress.org/plugins/role-scoper/) to disable this permissions. 
Or disable the line   **$actions['function']** in templates.php
function can be : approve, unapprove, spam, edit, quickedit